# Bundler not found using fish shell w/ rbenv

Tags: bundler, rbenv, fish

In attempting to use Bundler with ruby 1.9.3p194 managed with rbenv in the fish shell I receive the error:

```
> gem install bundler
Fetching: bundler-1.5.1.gem (100%)

> bundle install
fish: Unknown command 'bundle'
```

Rbenv is being initialized in `config.fish` like so:

```
set -x PATH "$HOME/.rbenv/bin" $PATH
. (rbenv init - | psub)
```

And the output of `rbenv init -`:

```
> rbenv init -
setenv RBENV_SHELL fish
. '/Users/nifl/.rbenv/libexec/../completions/rbenv.fish'
rbenv rehash 2>/dev/null
function rbenv
  set command $argv[1]
  set -e argv[1]

  switch "$command"
  case rehash shell
    eval (rbenv "sh-$command" $argv)
  case '*'
    command rbenv "$command" $argv
  end
end
```

I don't have fish set up as the default shell and Bundler is working fine in Bash.

Comment: what is the output of `rbenv init -`? I bet it spits out bash syntax not fish syntax

Comment: Turns out it's fish syntax. Edited question to show output.

Comment: Do you know how you got it to output fish status?  My version is still spitting out bash.  What version of rbenv are you running?  Or maybe it's some config setting that I'm missing...

Comment: I'm on rbenv 0.4.0-74-g95a039a. You may find your solution in rbenv issues searching for fish. https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/search?q=fish&ref=cmdform&type=Issues

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Derp. Needed rehash after `> gem install bundler`

```
> rbenv rehash
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I am the author of the question. I solved my issue w/ `rbenv rehash`

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize you self-answered this. You should accept your own answer to indicate that a solution has been found.

Answer (score 0):

Another issue that can appear is when using [rbenv-communal-gems](https://github.com/tpope/rbenv-communal-gems). jruby does not like the communization, it wants this:

```
rbenv sequester jruby-1.7.12
```

This allows you to re-run

```
gem install bundler
rbenv rehash
```

And then you can use the `bundle` command again.